# function passed HTMLAnchorElement is failing with script error

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a HTMLAnchorElement passed as parameter into a function. Purpose of function is to customise the anchor, setting target='_blank' and derives the href value, amongst other other customisation not shown here for simplicity.

```js
function CustomAnchor({
  htmlAnchorElement
}) {
  htmlAnchorElement.href = 'https://example.com';
  htmlAnchorElement.target = '_blank';
  return htmlAnchorElement ';
}

//  usage:
const MyComponent = () => {
  const anchorElement = < a > Click me < /a>;

  return ( <
    div >
    <
    CustomAnchor htmlAnchorElement = {
      anchorElement
    }
    /> </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render( < MyComponent / > , document.querySelector('#id1'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="id1">hello</div>
```

Comment: Seeing the code that attempts to create the anchor tag would help. As it is, nobody can possibly know what might be going on.

Comment: Please add any relevant code to your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: you should almost never need to imperatively set element attributes like that when using React. The fact you are doing so makes me suspicious that not only is it unnecessary, but that it's causing this issue as a result of this code being run at the wrong time, or not being cleaned up properly etc. But it's impossible to say for sure without seeing your component's code!